# How to know what kind of Multisignature address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, multi-signature

I have a Multisignature bitcoin for example address [3QJmV3qfvL9SuYo34YihAf3sRCW3qSinyC]

how to know what kind of it?

according to wiki https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Multisignature I have know Multisignature have below.

```
1-of-2
2-of-2
2-of-3
2-of-3
3-of-5
2-of-2
2-of-3
2-of-3
4-of-6
2-of-2
```

how to know [3QJmV3qfvL9SuYo34YihAf3sRCW3qSinyC] belongs to which type?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know, to which type an address of "3QJ...inyC" belongs, unless you created it yourself, or had the underlying data. Such a "type 3" address can be a hash of any data :-)

Ok, to be more precise for multisig: the address is probably created out of a redeem script (e.g. for a 2-of-3 multisig: <2><3>). This redeem script is hashed, and as a hash is a one way function (as per today's knowledge), you cannot reverse it.

You might have the chance to see which msig addresses / pubkeys and number of required sigs are included, when the spending transaction has been mined. Then you see all details of the redeemscript in the sigscript.

The way it works is described here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki. Much more details can be find in chapter 5 of Andreas' book "Mastering Bitcon, 2nd edition".

Comment: hello @pebwindkraft

Comment: Did you mean if I know the UTXO of mutisig address, I can get redeemscript from the sigscript?

Comment: No, when you can see the transaction e.g in a block explorer, like Blockchain.info. Background: the sigscript is normally the signature and the pubkey. And in a multi sig spending tax, the original redeemscript is placed instead of the pubkey... and then you see it once to is mined.